# form data validation of JSONObject in java controller

Tags: java, json, forms, validation

I have been assigned one task to add server side validation of user inputs. I have check the existing code and find that in controller they are getting String object from UI and then they are converting those to `JSONObject`. 
Now If I have to add validation : Example : Firstname must be not null, max lengh 50 etc.
What is the best way to do it without tightly coupled new validation code with existing code.

example of method in controller class  is :

```
JsonObject addClientInfo(String clientInfo,String callform){
    JSONObject clientObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(clientInfo);     
    ----  // existing application logic 
}
```

SO It's clear to me that I have to add validation logic after its creating JsonObject.  But should I directly start adding if-else in the same above method block or is there any better way?

Comment: An alternative & modern approach is to render `JSONObject` to a Java Bean and add bean validation.

Comment: Yes thats true, but the existing code is not well written and they are passing String (either json or orignal string param) till DAO layer and use it there. I realize converting to bean and validating it and then passing them to each method will required lots of code change in each layer plus also re-writing of each existing test case which is lots of efforts.